# Using commands inside an ANT task - escaping percentage signs?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ant

I've got the following .bat file that uses the command line interface for Confluence to add labels to pages based on a list in a text file (Test.txt). Here are the contents of the the bat file, which works fine, and which must be run from a particular location in an Atlassian directory:

```
cmd /k for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (Test.txt) DO (confluence --action addLabels --labels Expert --space CONTROL --title "%%A")
```

It picks up a list of page titles in Test.txt, and then runs the Confluence command to add the label "Expert" to each of those pages.

Now I'm trying to run this as an exec task as part of an ANT build. I was successful at using an ANT exec task to just call and run the .bat file, but I want to see if I can just run the commands from inside the ANT task directly instead of even having a .bat file.

It seems to be close, but I'm getting errors around the %%A parts. Here's the ANT task I have now:

```
 <target name="runBat">
  <exec os="Windows 7"   dir="C:\Developer\atlassian-cli-3.9.0" executable="cmd">
  <arg value="/c"/>
  <arg value="cmd /k for /F &quot;usebackq delims=&quot; %%A in (FAS_Test.txt) DO (confluence --action addLabels --labels Expert --space confluenceSpaceName --title &quot;%%A&quot;)"/></exec>
  </target>
```

Here are the latest error messages from the command line:

```
runBat:
    [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
    [exec] Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
    [exec] '/c'
    [exec] 'cmd /k for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (FAS_Test.txt) DO (confluence --action addLabels --labels Expert --space CONTROL --title "%%A")'
    [exec]
    [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    [exec] not part of the command.
    [exec] %%A was unexpected at this time.
    [exec] Result: 1
```

I've tried various things to escape the percentage signs but nothing works. I'm thinking that the percentage signs being doubled means that they're already escaped, but in a way that works in the .bat file but doesn't work in my ANT task. Not sure. Anyone who can help? I've tried:

```
  %A
 |%A 
 \%A 
 |%|%A 
 \%\%A
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found this finally and it seems to work

```
^%A
```

So in the .bat file it needs to be `%%A` and in the ANT task command it needs to be `^%A`.